# Struggling with regex PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to put a regex match in PHP to find whether the string contains any other invalid characters other than the following characters,

```
~!@#$%^&*()_-+=\}]{[::'"/>.<,
alpha, space, numeric
```

I want to print the string if it contains any other character other than the previously mentioned characters

```
ßab? - Invalid
Ba,-  - Valid
```

I tried using `preg_match` with few inputs but unable to complete it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

This expression will match the negative set of your valid range:

```
$valid = preg_quote('~!@#$%^&*()_-+=\}]{[::\'"/>.<,', '/');

if (preg_match("/[^$valid\d\sA-Za-z]/", $invalid)) {
        echo "invalid chars\n";
}
```

I'm using `preg_quote()` here to make sure all characters are properly escaped.

**Old answer**

I calculated the negative set based on your question:

```
if (preg_match('/[\x00-\x08\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x3b\x3f\x60\x7c\x7f-\xff]/', $str)) {
        echo "matches invalid chars\n";
}
```

To arrive at this set, you can use this code:

```
$s = '~!@#$%^&*()_-+=\}]{[::\'"/>.<,'
        . join('', range('a', 'z'))
        . join('', range('A', 'Z'))
        . join('', range('0', '9'))
        . " \t\r\v\n";

$missing = count_chars($s, 2);
print_r($missing);
```

It prints an array of ordinal character codes that's not inside `$s`; with that you can generate above pattern.

Comment: The regex seems to fail when i insert numbers

Comment: @w00 Could you give an example?

Comment: @w00 That's funny. I misread my calculator :) fixed. 0x36 instead of 0x3b

Comment: +1, although... @user1518659 FYI: `preg_quote()` is a bit of a carpet-bomb approach to the escaping here. The only characters that need to be escaped in a character class are `^\]-` and the delimiter, a caret only needs to be escaped if it is the first character in the set and a hyphen only if failure to do so would indicate a character range. However, what has been done above will still work fine, and I think this is probably the best approach from a readability and maintainability perspective.

Comment: The `/` must be escaped too and the backslash needs to written as ` \\\\ ` ;-) too much headache!

Comment: can you please tell how to generate the negative character set from ordinal character codes? @Jack

Comment: @user1518659 I basically handcrafted that from the `print_r($missing);` found in my answer :-)

Comment: thx. I mean how that "\x00-\x08" are generated? what do they represent? @Jack

Comment: @user1518659 `\x00-\x08` is just ordinal values 0 thu 8; it's like a range shorthand for regular expressions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26082/discussion-between-user1518659-and-jack)

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match any string that contains your special characters,alpha, space, numeric..

```
/^[\s\w~!@#$%^&*()+=\}\]{\[:'"\/>.<,-]*$/
```

`^` is the start of the string..`$` is the end of the string..`^`,`$` are required because they would match the input **exactly** instead of partially

`[]` is a character class which would match any **one** of the characters within it..

`*` is a quantifier which would match preceeding character,group or character class **0 to many** times..

Comment: You forgot to escape the `/` in your valid character list. Should be `\/` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: it is showing error at the position of "#"? where is the problem?

Comment: also don't we need to escape ' and " ?

Comment: @user1518659 i don't know about php and it's escape sequence..but it does work [here](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php)(an online php regex tester)

Comment: It is showing this string "ßab" as valid match. But it is invalid.

Comment: @user1518659 **no**..it's not matching...tested it [here](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

Comment: I believe you need to escape the `-` character aswell, as this implies a "range" of characters. Also the single quote or double quote must be escaped. And this also doesn't match for backslashes `\`. Try it with this regex: `/^[\s\w~!@#$%^&*()+=\}\]{\[:\'"\/>.<,\-\\\\]+$/` -- http://codepad.viper-7.com/NBVO1I (something is wrong with the formatting in this comment, can't get it right)